# SharePoint site collection: relation with DB WSS_Content

Tags: sharepoint, database

What's relationship between DB WSS_Content and SharePoint site collection? Is separated DB created per each site collection or a single DB can contain multiple collections?

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single DB can contain multiple site collections.
And a single web application can have multiple content databases.

Alternatively put:
A web app 'contains' 0 or more content databases. 
A content database then contains 0 or more site collections.

Comment: Exactly correct, just one additional thing a site collection can only be tied to one Content Database.

Comment: Thank you, BigPedro and Shaneo!

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint Terminology – Farms, Web Front Ends, Web Application and Sites](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/07/sharepoint-terminology-farm-web-application-site-collection-top-level-site/#more-1159)

> Each s[ite collection can only use a
> single content database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mcsnoiwb/how-to-create-site-collection-in-a-specific-content-database) (though
> multiple site collections can use the
> same content database) – this has
> major design implications as there are
> [maximum recommended sizes for a
> content database](https://web.archive.org/web/20120924064740/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joelo/archive/2007/01/31/tips-on-site-collection-sizing.aspx).